# Laravel Many to Many, how to insert/get data inside the pivot table?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, relationship

in laravel 9 I implement many to many relationship.

I have three table, `shop`  , `product`  and `product_shop` table.

each shop can have `number` of every single product.
and each product can exist in multiple shops.

the question is how can I insert/get the `number` of product inside the `product_shop` table?

what relationship syntax I have to use?

product_shop table :

```
$table->unsignedInteger('product_id');
$table->unsignedInteger('shop_id');
$table->unsignedInteger('number');

$table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
$table->foreign('shop_id')->references('id')->on('shops');
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pivot`. For example,

```
$product = $shop->products()->withPivot(['number'])->first();
$number = $product->pivot->number;
```

And if you want to insert,

```
$shop->products()->attach([$product_id => ['number' => $your_value]]);
```

Comment: `$product = $shop->products()->withPivot(['number'])->first();` how can I set the query? for example , `where('number', '>' , "5')` ?

Comment: `$product = $shop->products()->withPivot(['number'])->wherePivot('number', '>', 5)->get();`
It works for me

Comment: sorry, I could not found that how can I update the `number` field id pivot table ?